# SQL::Abstract generate insert with select query

Tags: sql, perl, sqlite, sql-generation

`insert into table1(id, text) select (max(id)+1), "Something" from table1`

How to generate this query with SQL::Abstract or SQL::Abstract::More?

Comment: Can you please explain what you have tried? There are some basic flaws in your SQL statement there.

Comment: I just wanna understand to how to make some complicated queries with SQL::Abstract or SQL::Abstract::More. I know about some flaws in this statement I just got it for example.

Comment: @koriander you're right, it's not enough.

Comment: you can also try Teng

Comment: You probably need to explain your problem more clearly.  Your sample SQL is not valid SQL, and it also does not make clear what you are attempting to do.

Comment: "Your sample SQL is not valid SQL"
Why? Please explain it. In http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html it is legal syntax for it.

Comment: Apparently SQLite is ok with double quoted strings as values - I don't think that's standard.  Certainly, it doesn't work in SQL Server or Postgres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use SQL::Abstract;

my $sa = SQL::Abstract->new;
my $select = $sa->select('table1', "MAX(id) + 1, 'Something'");
my $full_sql = "INSERT INTO table1 (id, text) $select";
```

But really, why would you?  Your example is trivial and, as pointed out by others, better served by just writing the SQL.  If you intended "something" to be a variable, you could do this:

```
my $new_id = $sa->select('table1', 'MAX(id) + 1');
my $data = {
   id => \["($new_id)"],
   text => $some_value_from_elsewhere
};
my ($sql, @binds) = $sa->insert('table1', $data);
```

Comment: I like your solution. Thanks. Bounty is yours!

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL statement contains, as Rachcha pointed out, some flaws. I assume you're trying something like

```
insert into table1(id, text) values((select (max(id)+1) from table1), "Something")
```

If you want to add new data into table1 with a unique ID you should really, really consider to add a primary key to your id field in the database.

**Updated answer**

The old anwser **does** create a valid SQL-statement regarding data and syntax but the *prepare* and *execute* function in DBI does some magic with the values.

If i run the query like this:

```
my $query = "insert into table1 values((select (max(id)+1) from table1), 'Something')";
$dbh->do($query);
```

The query will be left as is while executed. When I instead use the *prepare* and *execute*, DBI automatically puts the values between single quotes like 'this' which result in:

```
insert into table1(id, text) values('(select (max(id)+1) from table1)', 'Something');
```

Obviously, this will print the value as text (if that's a valid data type). This does in my opinion not mean that the generated query from the code is faulty rather than the unwanted quotations from DBI. I can't find an anwser to if it's possible to remove them. The question is if DBI supports an insert ... select statement at all. If not, you won't be able to use SQL::Abstract (or prepare/execute) with these querys.

You could build this as a two step rocket as long as you don't have multiple transactions to your database which could cause duplicates.

```
my $select_stmt = $sql->select('table1', '(max(id)+1)'):
# Prepare with $stmt
# Fetch your result and declare $max_id, e.g.
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($select_stmt);
$sth->execute();

my $max_id = 0;
my @max_id_arr = $sth->fetchrow_array();
$max_id = $max_id_arr[0];

die($max_id . " is 0") unless($max_id);

my %data = (
    id => $max_id,
    text => 'Something',
);

my($insert_stmt, @insert_bind) = $sql->insert('table1', \%data);
```

**Old answer**

However, to reply to your question, this should do the trick:

```
my $max_id = $sql->select('table1', 'max(id)+1');
my %data = (
    id => "($max_id)",
    text => "Something",
);
my($stmt, @bind) = $sql->insert('table1', \%data);

printf("My SQL statement was %s\nThe values was %s\n", $insert_stmt, join(", ", @insert_bind));
```

This will print

> My SQL statement was INSERT INTO table1 ( id, text) VALUES ( ?, ? )
>   The values was (SELECT max(id)+1 FROM table1), Something

Comment: The result of your code: 
`sqlite> select * from table1;
1|ahsdf
select max(id)+1 from table1|Something`
So it doesn't work well.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I haven't tried select in select with DBI before but I updated my anwser to a solution that might work for you even though it's not that smart.

Comment: I want to create the sql statement in one step. I can do the same thing in two step or even without SQL::Abstract but I have to learning how to create complicated queries with this module if it possible. The syntax of my statement is right and it's allowed by [SQLite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html). And thanks for your attention anyway.

Comment: I understand. However, the old anwser **is** a correct SQL statement, the reason it doesn't work is because when you execute it, the value gets caught between two single quotes. So the code I wrote does what you asked for, generates the correct statement. What you need to look for is how to pass this variable to the DBI-module and strip the quotations, `values('(select max(id)+1 from table1)')` must be changed to `values((select max(id)+1 from table1)`. I looked at the DBI docs but didn't find the anwser. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

While I use SQL::Abstract a lot in my code, I would not recommend it in your example. Mainly because it is sometimes more readable and maintainable if you write SQL-Code directly. And because you have to make sure that the order of the insert fields exactly match the order of the select fields.

You could however use the `$sql->where()` method to extract the where-part from your select query, if you have to:

```
    my $stmt1 = <<'END_SQL';
    INSERT INTO table1(id, text) 
    SELECT (MAX(id)+1) id, 'Something' text
    FROM table1
    END_SQL

    my ($stmt2,@binds) = $sql->where( key1=>$value1, key2=>$value2 );
```

And then simply concatenate the two SQL-statements.